# Form to email, file upload difficulties

Tags: php, forms, file, email, upload

I am relatively new to `php` but learning as I go. I am creating a tenant application form for my business, and have got the form working with basic text, dropdown fields, etc. Now I need to add a file upload to the form that will be sent to my email.

Can anyone please spare the time to add in the file upload as an attachment as I've tried a few different code snippets but struggled with it.

the `HTML` for the form is quite lengthy, I will post it if required but i have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `form` tab, name for inout is file_upload.

Heres my form handler, which may well be a long way round but it works presently

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
    $email_to = "REMOVED";
    $email_subject = "TENANT APPLICATION";

    function died($error) {

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    $property = $_POST['property'];  
    $title = $_POST['title']; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
    $dateofbirth = $_POST['dateofbirth']; 
    $nationality = $_POST['nationality']; 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; 
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $natins = $_POST['natins'];
    $smoker = $_POST['smoker'];
    $bankrupt = $_POST['bankrupt'];
    $ccj = $_POST['ccj']; 
    $currentaddress = $_POST['currentaddress']; 
    $tenancy = $_POST['tenancy'];
    $timeataddress = $_POST['timeataddress']; 
    $employmentstatus = $_POST['employmentstatus']; 
    $company = $_POST['company']; 
    $positionheld = $_POST['positionheld']; 
    $salary = $_POST['salary']; 
    $timeatemployer = $_POST['timeatemployer']; 
    $selfemployedinfo = $_POST['selfemployedinfo']; 
    $selfemployedincome = $_POST['selfemployedincome'];
    $otheroccupantsover18 = $_POST['otheroccupantsover18'];
    $otheroccupantsunder18 = $_POST['otheroccupantsunder18'];
    $pets = $_POST['pets']; 


    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Property applied for: ".clean_string($property)."\n\n";

       $email_message .= "APPLICANT DETAILS.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Title: ".clean_string($title)."\n";
    $email_message .= "First name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date of birth: ".clean_string($dateofbirth)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "National insurance : ".clean_string($natins)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Smoker : ".clean_string($smoker)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Bankrupt : ".clean_string($bankrupt)."\n";   
    $email_message .= "CCJ's : ".clean_string($ccj)."\n\n";


      $email_message .= "CURRENT ADDRESS DETAILS.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Current address: ".clean_string($currentaddress)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Type of tenancy: ".clean_string($tenancy)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Time at current address: ".clean_string($timeataddress)."\n\n";

      $email_message .= "PREVIOUS ADDRESS DETAILS.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Previous address 1: ".clean_string($previousaddressone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Previous address 2: ".clean_string($previousaddresstwo)."\n\n";

      $email_message .= "EMPLOYMENT.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Employment status: ".clean_string($employmentstatus)."\n\n";

       $email_message .= "EMPLOYED DETAILS.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Position held: ".clean_string($positionheld)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Salary: ".clean_string($salary)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Time with employer: ".clean_string($timeatemployer)."\n\n";

       $email_message .= "SELF EMPLOYED DETAILS.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Details of self employment: ".clean_string($selfemployedinfo)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Average net income of past 3 years: ".clean_string($selfemployedincome)."\n\n";


       $email_message .= "OTHER OCCUPANTS.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "Other occupants OVER 18: ".clean_string($otheroccupantsover18)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Other occupants UNDER 18: ".clean_string($otheroccupantsunder18)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Details of any pets: ".clean_string($pets)."\n\n";



    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>

    <?php include 'thankyouapplicationform.php';?>


    <?php

    }
```

I have successfully got the following code working but this was a code snippet downloaded from somewhere, and i failed to merge the file upload part into my form handler

```
'''  <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['Name','Email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('Email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('Message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->attachFiles(['image']);


$pp->sendEmailTo('REMOVED'); // â† Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST); '''
```

`Edit` Here are the attempts I've made so far...

Comment: Please share with the community the attempts you already did.

Comment: I used a code snippet and this worked fine by itself, but the php coding was different to the code structure of my php handler which made integrating the file upload section tricky.

im also new to stackoverflow, and it wont let me post the code into the reply without going over the character count. shall i edit my original question instead?

Comment: You can edit your question and add the additional code

Comment: i have added the code that i tried to incorporate however i had no luck with it, probably as it was using an external file to handle the form.

Comment: Where about is the vendor directory. If it's in the root you may not have went back enough directories.

Comment: ah no i downloaded a code for it, to try and find out how to add file attachments to a form, and that code and everthing worked brilliantly, however i could not extract the file upload code, it may be that i cant, and im struggling to find code from somewhere that can just slot into my current form handler, due to different versions of code that i cant get my head around.